# Using clang-format with C++/CLI "for each"

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019, clang-format

I currently try to format C++/CLI code using *clang-format* (version 9.0.0). I cannot figure how to handle `for each` statements.

Before:

```
for each (auto i in I)
{
}
```

After (say, CTRL-K/CTRL-D in Visual Studio):

```
for
   each (auto i in I)
   {
   }
```

I read [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/364475/unwanted-clang-format-on-ccli.html) this:

> ...you might want to change ForEachMacros to add "for each"

I tried this:

```
ForEachMacros:
  - for each
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
```

then this:

```
ForEachMacros:
  - 'for each'
```

and this:

```
  - "for each"
```

and even this:

```
  - "for\s+each"
```

Nothing works. Is there a way to make it works? In the doc, it is written that it (`ForEachMacros`) is a vector of macros... so I don't see how a can create a macro with a space character inside!

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the final format that you are trying to achieve, is it like in the 'Before:' example above?

Comment: @ZedLepplin Yes, actually I want to have `for each (..`. `for` and `each` dispatched to two different lines don't compile. _Lexically_ speaking, it looks like `for each` is a single token containing a white space...???

Comment: my vs 2019 does not do what your version is doing. I would hardly ever change  the default settings so I would think my formatting rules are set to defaults. I will go and have a look.

Comment: @ZedLepplin I have VS2019 16.1.6, I use clangformat.exe v 9.0.0. I used --config Microsoft to generate the first .clang-format file and the problem was present at that time. I performed few changed for other settings and the `for each` problem remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the issue by defining your own macro, e.g. `#define FOR_EACH for each`, and use that macro instead of `for each`. E.g. `FOR_EACH(auto i in I)`.
Now clang-format will ignore it.

You can add it to your `.clang-format` file, `ForEachMacros: ['FOR_EACH']`, so it is handled as a loop instead of a function call for formatting. Not required for fixing compilation though.