# "for each" in C++/CLI: a token or two?

Tags: c++-cli, token

I'm asking this question after asking [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58995706/using-clang-format-with-c-cli-for-each?noredirect=1#comment104338268_58995706). We experience a line break problem with the `for each (...in...)` statement in C++/CLI formating.

***My question is quite simple: in C++/CLI, are `for each` two tokens for the tokenizer or a single one with a space (0x20) inside it?***

My point is that I tought that no token could contain a space but when they are split (by clang-format formatter) in two lines like this:

```
for
    each ( auto a in b )
    {
    }
```

I get the errors:

- C2061 syntax error: identifier 'each'
- C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

But when I write:

```
for each ( a in aa ) {}
```

I have no error.

Comment: According to [the documentation of for each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019), `for each` is a context sensitive **keyword**, hence the compiler errors. The documentation also mentions that its use is not recommended.

Comment: It is a keyword.  Whether it is recognized by the lexer or the parser is not obvious, source code has never been published.  No matter, doesn't help you anyway.  You are using the wrong tool, the VS auto-formatter has no trouble with it.  Use Edit > Advanced > Format Document.

Comment: @HansPassant Well... we were used to use _team settings_ and MS removed them in VS2019 (or VS2017? we were using VS2015). To allow team formatting, we have to use ClangFormat.exe. Not our first choice.